# Aligning multiple axes on MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, multiple-axes

I need to plot a bunch of unit vectors and histograms corresponding to both axes (as a simple way to visualize clustering).

This is what I want: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIeev.jpg.

- The axes for the histogram are aligned with the unit vector plot.

This is what I am getting: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8HA5.jpg

- The axes are misaligned

=

```
x = randn(100,1);
y = randn(100,1);
data = [x y];

normData = rowfun(@(n) n./norm(n,2),table(data)); 

xData = normData{:,:}(:,1);
yData = normData{:,:}(:,2);

blankFigure([-1 1 -1 1]);  hold on; 
cellfun(@(x,y) plot([0 x], [0 y],'LineWidth',3),num2cell(xData),num2cell(yData))

ax1 = gca;
ax1Pos = get(ax1,'Position');
ax2Pos = ax1Pos;
ax2Pos(2) = ax1Pos(2)-.05;
ax2 = axes('Position',ax2Pos);
edges = [-1:.1:1];
histogram(xData,edges,'Normalization','pdf','Orientation','vertical');
set(ax2,'XLim',get(ax1,'XLim'));
set(ax2,'YLim',[0 8]);
set(ax2,'Visible','off'); 

ax3Pos = ax1Pos;
ax3Pos(1) = ax1Pos(1)-.05;
ax3 = axes('Position',ax3Pos);
histogram(yData,edges,'Normalization','pdf','Orientation','horizontal')
set(ax3,'YLim',get(ax1,'YLim'));
set(ax3,'XLim',[0 8]);
set(ax3,'Visible','off')

set(ax1,'Visible','on');
```

Comment: I don't see what the problem is can you show some pictures?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @Benoit_11 . See edits above

Comment: ok thanks. I got the right output when I paste your code and delete this line: `blankFigure(...)` maybe that's the problem. Is it a function you created?